# Finding distance between two different point layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, distance, proximity

I have a large postcode dataset of ~1.6 million observations in *'Layer A'*.

I have a smaller dataset of ~5000 observations in *'Layer B'*.

*'Layer A'* contains an `"ID"` that matches postcodes with observations in *'Layer B'*.

I want to find the distance between every observation in *'Layer A'*, and the associated observation in *'Layer B'*, using the common `"ID"` field.

Note, I do not want to do Nearest Neighbor Analysis, there is a specific network structure.

Comment: So does each point in Layer A have a unique ID? And points in Layer B have a matching ID? Do multiple points in the same layer have the same ID?

Comment: Each point in Layer A has a unique ID (a postcode), and then an ID that matches the observations in Layer B. There shouldn't be multiple points in the same layer with the same ID.

Comment: Although the solution I posted deals with a fraction of points you have, perhaps you could consider using PostGIS for this? In which case, I'll happily delete my post as I don't think it will work well for that huge a dataset :)

Answer (score 4):

Create a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

[image]

Query:

```sql
SELECT LayerA.postcodes AS Postcodes, 
       st_distance(LayerA.geometry, LayerB.geometry) AS Distance
FROM   LayerA INNER JOIN LayerB
ON     LayerA.postcodes = LayerB.postcodes
```

Answer (score 2):

I would probably do the following:

1. Copy/paste your 5000 points from Layer B into Layer A (or run a merge tool).
2. Install the **Points2One** plugin from:

   ```
   Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...
   ```
3. Run this plugin on your merged layer.

---

Example:

1. A sample point layer created from two separate layers (both with a common `ID` field) where I merged them:

   [image: Sample point layer]
2. Then run the **Points2One** plugin selected the relevant options:

   [image: Points2One plugin interface]
3. Output line shapefile should contain lines for each unique postcode:

   [image: Output line shapefile]
4. Use the **Field Calculator** on the output to create a new field containing the distance values using the expression `$length`:

   [image: Final result]

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem: The Receiver layer had 48600 points and I needed to find the closest point in the Source layer (15900 points).

QGIS>Vector>Analysis Tools> Distance Matrix.
1."Input point layer": Receiver

2.Input Layer Unique ID - important to be unique

3."Target point layer": Source

4.Target Layer Unique ID - important to be unique

5."Use only the nearest (k) target points": 1 (for me, for you 9999999)

This produced a ascii file with: Input Layer Unique ID, Target Layer Unique ID and then the Distance.

For more information:
https://www.researchgate.net/post/How-to-calculate-the-distance-between-points-in-Qgis

Comment: Web links can support answers, but the meat of the content should be in the Answer, since links fail over time. Please edit this Answer to contain more about the solution.

Comment: Thanks Vince, I've edited my answer.